# Convert a lambda to a dotted string e.g. x => x.Address.City becomes Address.City

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to convert a lambda expression referencing a property or sub-property of an object, e.g. `x => x.Address.City` into a string `Address.City`.  Is there an existing framework method (MVC, EF, ...?) that does this or do I need to roll my own?  If the latter, any code out there already that does this?

Comment: What should happen if the lambda expression is `x => x.Total * 2`?

Comment: @Mark Then it isn't a valid expression type

Comment: @Marc: Don't care, exception would be fine.  Same behavior as MVCwhen it uses lambdas to refer to properties would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, MVC has this ability built in. It's used in the HTML Helpers, which can take an expression and render an `<input name = "Address.City">`. Look in ExpressionHelper.cs in the MVC source code.